# How to link all buttons to another page using onclick class or by tagname

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem where I cant seem to get all the buttons on my page to link to another page, it does work with an ID or using a specific element for example:document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].onclick

But doing document.getElementsByTagName("button").onclick (so all buttons)
or doing document.getElementsByClassName("theButtons").onclick
doesnt work.

My Javascript code:

```
window.onload = function(){
            document.getElementsByTagName("button").onclick = function () {
            location.href = "../index.html";
            };
        };

<button class="theButtons">click me</button>
<button class="theButtons">click me</button>
<button class="theButtons">click me</button>
```

Comment: The `getElements` functions return array-like objects that you will have to iterate over.

Comment: Is there not a canonical for this? I couldn't find one.

Comment: @4castle - It is not an array though, it is a live HTMLCollection.

Comment: @TravisJ Yup, I knew that. I've run into that when trying to use `forEach`. (You can't use `forEach` btw OP)

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through the collection of buttons in your document. `document.getElementsByTagName()` returns a collection of all of the elements that match, so you must loop through that array and assign the `onClick` of each item.

```
window.onload = function(){
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        var button = buttons[i];
        button.onclick = function () { location.href = "../index.html"; };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because [`document.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) will return a HTMLCollection, [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) will return an DOM element. HTMLCollection cannot add any event listener.

You can try:

1. use `for` loop go though the array, register `click` event handler to each `button`.
2. use [event bubbling](http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing). Register one event handler on the container to listen all the event on its children. (Recommend).

Hope this usefull.

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to use Jquery `click()` see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/85qLh41a/3/

```
<button class="theButtons">click me</button>
<button class="theButtons">click me</button>
<button class="theButtons">click me</button>
<script>
  $(".theButtons").click(function() {
    location.href = '../index.html';
  });
</script>
```

Or this will work to, for all button's on the page

```
<script>
  $("button").click(function() {
    location.href = '../index.html';
  });
</script>
```